# Is there a desktop equivalent to the Play! Framework?

Tags: java, playframework-1.x

Having gained an interest in Java and JPA by means of the Play! Framework 1.x, I'm interested in doing similar for desktop apps.

Is there a Java framework for non-Web Desktop GUI apps that has the ease of development and ease of deployment that Play! web apps gives?  Anything that abstracts all the intricacies and lets me just focus on code...

Comment: What's wrong with vanilla Java for Desktop apps?

Comment: jar files, dependencies, compile, test debug fix recompile - things that Play hides away from me. If I can hide those things away as easily as Play does for my webapps, then great. Also, lots of UI toolkits hard to decide which to adopt...

Comment: Also, I like Play Framework's MVC model - just wanna replace the "View" component with desktop instead of Web

Comment: Maven/Buildr can take care of your first problems in deployment (dependencies, compilation, testing, etc.). For local development, if you use a proper IDE, your arguments don't make sense. If you can't pick what UI tookit to use, chances are, you'll be perfectly fine with Swing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try [Griffon](http://griffon-framework.org/), its based on Grails (groovy rulezzz) and abstracts a lot of the boilerplate code of desktop development in Java, also there is a netbeans plugin and you can use the matisse designer for the UI.

Comment: Thanks for bringing Griffon to my knowledge. Had not heard of it before.

Answer (score 3):

Griffon comes very close to what you may be looking for. If you favor Scala over other JVM languages then you'll find that Griffon supports it https://bintray.com/griffon/griffon-archetypes without a hitch, you can even build a full blown Scala application with it.

In terms of UI: Swing, JavaFX or SWT? Griffon has you covered.
Persistence? No sweat (including JPA http://griffon-plugins.github.io/griffon-jpa-plugin/ and Ebean http://griffon-plugins.github.io/griffon-ebean-plugin/).

Every Griffon distribution includes a copy of the Griffon Guide, you're first stop shop for learning Griffon http://griffon-framework.org/guide/latest/